# Proof by induction on matrix

Tags: matrices, induction

Can you show, please, how proof this type of exercises by induction. Trying to understand the pattern
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}^n=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2^n-1 \\
0 & (-1)^n & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2^n \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Can you prove the base case? What happens when you try to start the induction hypothesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(-1)^0=2^0=1$, this is true for $n=0$.

Now, assuming that :

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}^n=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2^n-1 \\
0 & (-1)^n & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2^n \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is true for some positive integer $n$, we have :

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}^{n+1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2^n-1 \\
0 & (-1)^n & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2^n
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2^{n+1}-1 \\
0 & (-1)^{n+1} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2^{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
as expected.